# Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV) and incomplete implementation of class error

Tags: objective-c, recursion

I am writing a small recursive function to calculate the sum of integers from an array. However, I am getting errors and warnings. Anybody help me to solve these issues?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SumIntegers:NSObject
{
    NSInteger result;
}

-(NSInteger)calcutateSum:(NSInteger)value;
-(void) printSum;

@end

@implementation SumIntegers

-(NSInteger)calculateSum:(NSInteger)value
{
    NSInteger sum = 0;

        //sum = sum + [[self calculateSum:[array objectAtIndex:i]] integerValue];
        sum = sum + [self calculateSum:value];


    result = sum;
    return result;
}

-(void) printSum
{
    NSLog(@"Sum of integer list is %i",result);
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSInteger i;
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *intArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]
                ,[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9],nil];

    SumIntegers *sumIntegers = [[SumIntegers alloc]init];

    for (i = 0; i<[intArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSInteger hhh = [sumIntegers calculateSum:[[intArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];
    }

    [sumIntegers printSum];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

What I did is I created an interface SumIntegers and created a recursive function to calculate the sum of integers. However, somehow this function is not recognized and also getting warning "incomplete implementation of class @end" and memory error.

```
Warning(s):
source_file.m:31:1: warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘SumIntegers’
 @end
 ^
source_file.m:31:1: warning: method definition for ‘-calcutateSum:’ not found
source_file.m: In function ‘main’:
source_file.m:44:19: warning: unused variable ‘hhh’ [-Wunused-variable]
         NSInteger hhh = [sumIntegers calculateSum:[[intArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];
                   ^
Error(s):
Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: first calcutateSum should be "calculateSum" second you're calling "[self calculateSum:]" method in your calcutateSum method that is not there?

Comment: Thanks, few issues resolved but it is the recursive function, that's why I need to call within that function.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things. What are you trying to do? Why a recursive method? The argument of `calculateSum:` is a `NSMutableArray*` (= pointer) and you're trying to call `calculateSum:` with a `NSInteger` argument.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I am doing one exercise to write a recursive method to calculate the sum. I am now writing the edited version of this problem with different errors. Please check that too.

Comment: Is this from a tutorial or book?   This looks not at all like patterns used in modern objc.

Comment: Somebody send me this exercise. However, I am trying to solve it by the simpler way also but the main problem is to write a recursive function that will sum a list of integers.

Comment: @WasimSafdar There is no reason to use recursion here.  But if you were to force recursion on this, this wouldn't be the way.  Your recursive function or method needs some condition under which it stops recursing.  As written, your recursive method has no such condition;  it'll recurse forever and crash (SIGSEGV is a reasonable crash in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to above problem. There is no need of return value or argument in the calculateSum method. Simply adding array value into the sum and then calling the calculateSum method again until num is less than array count.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SumOfIntegers:NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *intArray;
    NSInteger sum;
    NSInteger num;
}

@property NSMutableArray *intArray;
@property NSInteger sum, num;

-(void) calculateSum;
@end

@implementation SumOfIntegers
@synthesize intArray, sum, num;

-(void) calculateSum{

    if(num < [intArray count])
    {
        NSLog(@"number is.... %i", num);

        sum = sum + [[intArray objectAtIndex:num++] integerValue];
        [self calculateSum];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Sum of integers is %i", sum);
    }

}    
@end

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]
                ,[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9],nil];

    SumOfIntegers *sumOfIntegers = [[SumOfIntegers alloc]init];
    sumOfIntegers.intArray = array;
    sumOfIntegers.sum = 0;
    sumOfIntegers.num = 0;

    [sumOfIntegers calculateSum];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@synthesize` and you don't need to declare both @property and instance variables.   And you should be using ARC, thus no autoreleasepool is needed either (though @autoreleasepool{} would be needed in main().  Whatever exercises you are doing, it looks like it is for an antiquated version of ObjC.

Comment: Yes, the compiler I was using was an old one.

Answer (score 0):

In modern ObjC:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *nums = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)];
        NSLog(@"%@", [nums valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```